# Fold function scala's immutable list

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have created an immutable list and try to fold it to a map, where each element is mapped to a constant string "abc". I do it for practice. 
While I do that, I am getting an error. I am not sure why the map (here, e1 which has mutable map type) is converted to Any.

```
val l = collection.immutable.List(1,2,3,4)
l.fold (collection.mutable.Map[Int,String]()) ( (e1,e2) => e1 += (e2,"abc") )

l.fold (collection.mutable.Map[Int,String]()) ( (e1,e2) => e1 += (e2,"abc") )
<console>:13: error: value += is not a member of Any
  Expression does not convert to assignment because receiver is not assignable.
       l.fold (collection.mutable.Map[Int,String]()) ( (e1,e2) => e1 += (e2,"abc") )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Folding is all about combining a sequence of input elements into a single output element. The output and input elements should have the same types in Scala. Here is the definition of `fold`:

```scala
  def fold[A1 >: A](z: A1)(op: (A1, A1) => A1): A1
```

In your case type `A1` is `Int`, but output element (sum type) is `mutable.Map`. So if you want to build a `Map` throug iteration, then you can use `foldLeft` or any other alternatives where you can use different input and output types. Here is the definition of `foldLeft`:

```scala
def foldLeft[B](z: B)(op: (B, A) => B): B
```

Solution:

```scala
val l = collection.immutable.List(1, 2, 3, 4)
l.foldLeft(collection.immutable.Map.empty[Int, String]) { (e1, e2) =>
  e1 + (e2 -> "abc")
}
```

Note: I'm not using a mutabe `Map`

Comment: Thanks for making me to realize that fold fold takes same type (or subtype) element of the list. That was the mistake I was committing. I am wondering why the inputs of fold and foldLeft  are made different.

Answer (score 3):

At least three different problem sources here:

1. `Map[...]` is not a supertype of `Int`, so you probably want `foldLeft`, not `fold` (the `fold` acts more like the ["banana brackets"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catamorphism), it expects the first argument to act like some kind of "zero", and the binary operation as some kind of "addition" - this does not apply to mutable maps and integers).
2. The binary operation must return *something*, both for `fold` and `foldLeft`. In this case, you probably want to return the modified map. This is why you need `; m` (last expression is what gets returned from the closure).
3. The `m += (k, v)` is not what you think it is. It attempts to invoke a method `+=` with **two** separate arguments. What you need is to invoke it with a single pair. Try `m += ((k, v))` instead (yes, those problems with arity are annoying).

Putting it all together:

```
l.foldLeft(collection.mutable.Map[Int, String]()){ (m, e) => m += ((e, "abc")); m }
```

But since you are using a mutable map anyway:

```
val l = (1 to 4).toList
val m = collection.mutable.Map[Int, String]()
for (e <- l) m(e) = "abc"
```

This looks arguably clearer to me, to be honest. In a `foldLeft`, I wouldn't expect the map to be mutated.